# Class based views: get_context_data method

Tags: django, python-3.x

I know what it's purpose is, and I know how to use it.  But I'm curious, what is the code actually doing and why it is written the way i?

I'm referring to this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CreateListing, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['action'] = reverse('create-listing')
    return context
```

So I'm creating a dict called context that the Django base controller class is manipulating on the back end?  Or am I off?  The super part is what really throws me off because I'm not sure what relevant information I'm getting from it.

Answer (score 0):

The super call is getting the context from whatever `CreateListing`s super class is.  It's so that you can subclass the view and add more context in each of the subclasses - exactly like in this instance where you're adding `action` to the context.